# getaddrinfo error:ai_socktype not supported

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I am writing one code which tell the ip address of domain. The following code works fine.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <sys/socket.h>
#include  <sys/types.h> 
#include  <netdb.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <arpa/inet.h>

#define     SUCCESS 0
#define     FAILURE -1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if(argc != 2) {
    printf("./a.out <domain>\n");
    return FAILURE;
}
struct addrinfo src,*res,*var;
struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
int status;
src.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
src.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
src.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE;
if((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1],NULL,&src,&res))!=0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"getaddrinfo error:%s\n",gai_strerror(status));
    exit(1);
}
for(var = res;var != NULL;var = var->ai_next) {
    if(var->ai_family == AF_INET) {
        ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) var->ai_addr;
        inet_ntop(var->ai_family,&(ipv4->sin_addr),ipstr,INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    }
    else {
        ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) var->ai_addr;
        inet_ntop(var->ai_family,&(ipv6->sin6_addr),ipstr,INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    }
    printf("IP address:%s\n",ipstr);
}
freeaddrinfo(res);
freeaddrinfo(var);
return SUCCESS;
}
```

When I am trying to use the void * to store the struct sockaddr_in sin_addr or struct sockaddr_in6 sin6_addr I am getting following error.
**"getaddrinfo error:ai_socktype not supported"**

The code as follows

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <sys/socket.h>
#include  <sys/types.h> 
#include  <netdb.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <arpa/inet.h>

#define     SUCCESS 0
#define     FAILURE -1

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if(argc != 2) {
    printf("./a.out <domain>\n");
    return FAILURE;
}
struct addrinfo src,*res,*var;
struct sockaddr_in *ipv4;
struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6;
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
int status;
void *addr;
src.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
src.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
src.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE;
if((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1],NULL,&src,&res))!=0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"getaddrinfo error:%s\n",gai_strerror(status));
    exit(1);
}
for(var = res;var != NULL;var = var->ai_next) {
    if(var->ai_family == AF_INET) {
        ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) var->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
    }
    else {
        ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) var->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
    }
    inet_ntop(var->ai_family,addr,ipstr,INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("IP address:%s\n",ipstr);
}
freeaddrinfo(res);
freeaddrinfo(var);
return SUCCESS;
}
```

I am beginner to socket programming.Please help me to fix this.

Comment: After your loop `var` will be `NULL`, don't "free" it.

Comment: As for your error message, you get that *before* you even use the `addr` variable. Try clearing the whole `src` structure first, like e.g. `struct addrinfo src = { 0 }`. If you don't then the members you do not explicitly initialize contain seemingly random values.

Comment: Don't use `inet_ntop()`; use [`getnameinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html) instead. The [`man 3 getaddrinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) has two related example programs that you can examine in detail.